# NodeJS code executes differently when run via browser and when run via curl in terminal

Tags: node.js

I have the following simple NodeJS code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer( function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        response.write("This printed 3 secs later, ait?");
        response.end();
    }, 3000);

    response.write("This will be printed before.\n");
}).listen(8080);
```

If I run the script with `node scriptname.js` and then access it via curl in terminal like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

I get an output as expected, first it prints `This will be printed before.`, then after 3 seconds it prints `This printed 3 secs later, ait?`.

However, when I open `http://localhost:8080` in my browser (newest versions of Chrome, Firefox) page loads for 3 seconds and it prints the text `This will be printed before.
This printed 3 secs later, ait?` all at once. Why does this happen and how could I make the same behavior in the browser?

**edit:** So, as Ken stated in his answer

> ...this is simply due to the behavior of the browser rendering engine to render the contents. The rendering engine cashes the contents until  response.end();

and advised to go and check out Socket.IO, I came up with this working example which uses [express](http://expressjs.com/) and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/):

//timeoutTest.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/timeoutTest.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
   client.emit('msg', "This prints right now on connection.");

   setTimeout(function(){
      client.emit('msg', "This prints out after 3 secs.");      
   }, 3000);
});
```

//timeoutTest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var server = io.connect('http://localhost');
        server.on('msg', function(data){
            $('body').append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS. I have recommended to you `Socket.IO` for the starter of server-browser interaction issue. This technology is generally called `RPC(remote procedure cal)` . `Socket.IO` is familiar to many people and you can find abundant resource on the web, so good thing to start. Just for future references, I personally do not use it anymore since it's a huge library just to do RPC between node and browser. The more concise and sophisticated (I think) and seamless way to do RPC here is to use `https://github.com/substack/dnode or https://github.com/dominictarr/rpc-stream with 'Browserify'.

Comment: Please refer my answer to a related question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832402/is-socket-io-a-must-in-developing-client-apps-for-nodejs-servers

Comment: Thanks for additional comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is simply due to the behavior of the browser rendering engine to render the contents.

The rendering engine cashes the contents until 
`response.end();` arrives, then renders whole.

Basically, HTML contents in the browser are never updated automatically by incremental `server push` such as `response.write`.

You must `pull` data from the server to the browser client by Ajax and DHTML/js technique.

curl in terminal is completely different story in terms of the mere output of the node server.

If you seek more interactive behavior between `node` server and browser client, if you want `server push` feature, `websocket` is the way to go, and also investigate `node  stream` stuff.

`Socket.IO` is famous, and for `node stream`
https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook should be interesting to you.

I personally do this on my own project:

http://kenokabe.github.io/MarkdownLive/

I write stuff using Markdown and needed a streaming preview, so I created by myself. The preview screen is a Browser HTML page, and the HTML contents rendered and updated incrementally in streaming manner.

Comment: Thanks Ken, your answer made me go and explore this further. You can check out what I came up with in my edit. Thx!

Comment: It's my pleasure, Nikola. Glad to hear that my little comment help you.